# Pull a random value from a list if another column has a value in same row

Tags: excel, list, random

I have a list of named entities and a chart of how often they have been audited:

```
Name   May  June  July  Aug
Alpha  2    1     1     
Beta   1    1     
Gamma  1    1     1
Delta  1    1
```

I'm trying to have a cell display who in a given month wasn't audited at least once.

The best I have managed has been using two cells, one named as "RandNum" with

```
=INDEX(A2:A5,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(A2:A5)))
```

and another cell that i use to get a random returned value, if the value it returned has been audited for that month it says "Try Again." In example 4 is the column for July. When I hit delete on a blank cell it updates.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(RandA,A2:E5,4)>=1,RandNum,"Try Again")
```

I'd rather not resort to VBA if I can help it but I'm open to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,LARGE((INDEX($B$2:$E$5,,MATCH(D9,$B$1:$E$1,FALSE))=0)*(ROW($A$2:$A$5)),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(INDEX($B$2:$E$5,,MATCH(D9,$B$1:$E$1,FALSE)),""))),1)
```

Put the month you want in D9 and enter the above as an array formula (Ctrl+Shft+Enter)

```
INDEX($B$2:$E$5,,MATCH(D9,$B$1:$E$1,FALSE))
```

This part is in two places. It returns the column in question. If you put July in D9, it will return D2:D5. If you put Aug it will return E2:E5. If you misspell something, you'll get an error.

```
(INDEX(...)=0)*(ROW($A$2:$A$5))
```

This returns an array that, for July, looks like `{0,3,0,5}` and for August looks like `{2,3,4,5]`.

```
RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(INDEX(...),""))
```

This picks a random number between 1 and the count of all the blank cells in the column.

```
LARGE(array,RANDBETWEEN(...))
```

This picks the nth largest row in the array, where nth is random. It won't pick one that's already been audited because those are zero in the array and zero won't ever be the largest (unless everyone's been audited).

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,LARGE(...),1)
```

Finally, the nth largest row is put in an INDEX to return the name.

Answer (score 0):

I added a helper column and created a bunch of names:

[image]

"Name" refers to A2:A5, "May" refers to B2:B5, ... "indices" refers to F2:F5 (all done almost instantly with `Create from selection` in the name part of the formula tab, but make sure you use the top row and not the left column for the source of names). I also made "Target" refer to A8. Then in F2 I entered:

```
=IF(INDEX(INDIRECT(Target),1+ROW()-ROW(Name)) = 0,1+ROW()-ROW(Name),0)
```

And copied it down through F5. Finally in the highlighted cell I entered:

```
=INDEX(Name,LARGE(indices,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(indices, ">0"))))
```

This is (I think) what you want. Also, rather than hitting delete on a blank cell, `F9` is the standard way to trigger a worksheet calculation (which might be good to know if your entire screen is filled with cells whose values you don't want to delete).

Comment: I've been trying to implement this solution but I'm running into a circular reference error

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. My guess is that your names refer to ranges which are too large. In the above screenshot note that "May" is the name of B2:B5 *not* all of column B. If your name is so large that it encompasses the cell containing the final formula (B7 in this case) then you would get a circular reference. When I set up the names I selected A1:E5 before I invoked `Create from selection`. My guess is that you selected all of columns A to E before you did so.